# rewrite rule in nginx to remove extra '/' at the end

Tags: mod-rewrite, nginx

So I wanted to create a rewrite rule such that when a uses types in

```
mydomain.com/toplevel/secondlevel/
```

it rewrites it to

```
mydomain.com/toplevel/secondlevel
```

similarly if I have

```
mydomain.com/toplevel/
```

I wanted this to be

```
mydomain.com/toplevel
```

I understand that this can be done using the `rewrite` command and regex, but can't seem to find the right regex for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this rule to main `server` section:

```
rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
```

It removes slash at the end from any adress which contains it.